# boost coroutine using with boost future

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, boost-coroutine

I am trying to make map having the result of coroutine.
I searched for an example showing how to get future of coroutine.
I need to generate tasks to use them with asio afterwards.
this is the code for coroutine:

```
std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<HTTPResponse>> create_tasks(const symbols_enum& symbol, date day)
{
    int start = 0;

    if (is_dst(day))
    {
        start = 1;
    }

    ostringstream oss;
    oss << symbol;
    std::string url_currency{oss.str()};
    std::ostringstream().swap(oss); // swap m with a default constructed stringstream
    std::string url_year{day.year()};

    stringstream ss_month;
    ss_month << setw(2) << setfill('0') << ((day.month().as_number()) - 1);
    string url_month{ ss_month.str() };
    std::stringstream().swap(ss_month); // swap m with a default constructed stringstream

    stringstream ss_day;
    ss_day << setw(2) << setfill('0') << day.day().as_number();
    string url_day{ ss_day.str() };
    std::stringstream().swap(ss_day); // swap m with a default constructed stringstream

    std::string URL{ protocol_host_URL+"/"+"datafeed"+"/"+ url_currency +"/"+ url_year +"/"+ url_month +"/"+ url_day +"/" };

    HTTPClient client;


    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<HTTPRequest>> requests_variables;
    std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<HTTPResponse>> tasks;

    for (int hour = 0;hour < 24;hour++)
    {
        stringstream ss_hour;
        ss_hour << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour;
        string url_hour{ ss_hour.str() };
        std::stringstream().swap(ss_hour); // swap m with a default constructed stringstream
        URL = URL + url_hour +"h_ticks.bi5";

        std::string request_name = "request_" + std::to_string(hour);
        requests_variables[request_name] =  client.create_request(hour, URL);

        //requests_variables[request_name]->execute();//must be coroutine and i think it should be normal coroutine
        coroutine<boost::shared_ptr<HTTPResponse>>::pull_type response_future_coroutine_pull(requests_variables[request_name]->execute);
        tasks[request_name] = response_future_coroutine_pull.get();         

    }
    //tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(get]


        return tasks;

    }
```

This part of the code is showing the way I need to make future tasks.
It is based on the way python do to get futures for coroutines.
I could not understand how to do this in c++.
I am using asio in part but for the sake of using for loop I thought of making coroutine which will be contained in the for loop and its async functions will be run in asio service.
I don't know if my thinking is even right.
what I specifically need is an example of how to make a container of futures of coroutines...

Comment: You don't "get the future of a coro". But you can promise one from inside it, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `boost::coroutine` here. What you want is `std::aysnc`

```
std::map<std::string, std::future<boost::shared_ptr<HTTPResponse>>> tasks;
for (...) {
    ...
    tasks[request_name] = std::async(&HTTPRequest::execute, client.create_request(hour, URL));
}
```

When you want to wait for the responses

```
std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<HTTPResponse>> responses;
for (auto& pair : tasks) {
    response[pair.first] = pair.second.get();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but async will start new thread...i just want to implement it using minimal threads...it is for educational purpose...i need to know how to work with co routines with minimal threads...and if there are futures for co routines

Comment: The launch policy `std::launch::deferred` doesn't start any threads. The default launch policy is allowed to choose between threaded and deferred execution on a per-call basis. [See here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)